# WiFi connection dropping out for specific devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection

**Problem**
We've been having an issue with our home network where 2 Laptops are dropping connections whenever I use one of my laptops. After the WiFi connection is dropped, it takes a few minutes until the connection can be built up again to this device. I was away for a week and no problems occurred, as soon as I got back and used my laptop the problems came back. I don't have any problems with either of my laptops (1 MacBook Pro Sierra, 1 Asus Windows 10). Smartphones don't seem to be affected at all. The problematic laptops are on Windows, 1 Windows 8 and the other Windows 7.

**What I've tried**
I tried pinning the problem to a specific program on my laptops, but to no avail. The other questions I found on this topic, unfortunately, couldn't help me. I wanted to try using a static IP for the problematic laptops, but the router does not have the option when the DHCP server is enabled.
Side Question: Can a static IP be set from the PC?

**Setup**
Router: Technicolor TC 7200, set to 2.4GHz
WiFi Extender: TP-LINK RE450, repeats to 2.4GHz and 5GHz (5GHz not used, unfortunately not possible to turn off)

I don't know if this is the right forum, hoping to find a solution. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: "Can a static IP be set from the PC?"  Yes

Comment: Do any of your devices have the same IP by any chance?

Comment: what do you mean by same IP? I have them on at the same time sometimes, so no :/

Comment: do you think setting a static IP would help?

Comment: "I have them on at the same time sometimes" That doesn't stop them having the same IP address :)

Comment: See my answer [What happens if 2 devices want the same static IP address?](//superuser.com/a/889616)

Comment: well there are currently no static IPs set, they're all getting their IPs from the DHCP Server